# When will moderator election 2015 start?

Tags: discussion, election

It is mid march but I didn't saw any moderator election out yet. When does elections for moderator start?

Comment: There are no scheduled community moderator elections at this time.  See http://askubuntu.com/election

Comment: From last 4 years, elections start during jan or feb, but it is mid-march, why not elections yet?

Comment: Take a look at this, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286132/when-will-the-2015-community-moderator-election-begin, it might be related.

Comment: read comments and the answer, so the election is based on need not on time.

Comment: In that case it is.

Comment: actually - we ourselves cannot answer that one. Its not for us to call for an election. Stack Exchange mods do this. lets wait for a SE mod to reply to this.

Comment: @fossfreedom actually, [it looks like it *is* for you to call for an election.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7944/will-there-be-a-2013-14-moderator-election#comment23250_7945)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moderator elections are not guaranteed to happen every year.  They happen only when necessary.

> The community team periodically looks at the work load on graduated
>   sites and will reach out to the moderation team if it looks like more
>   help might be needed. Broadly, it's up to the moderation teams to
>   indicate whether they need additional hands, and how many sets of
>   hands would be ideal.
>
> Although we'll reach out to moderators on the anniversary of their
>   last election, just to see how they're doing, elections do not always
>   take place at the same time every year. Sometimes a year can even go
>   by without any election at all. Most elections are scheduled as a
>   result of moderators reaching out to Stack Exchange to ask for
>   additional help.  [(source)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99515/152101)

Additionally, sometimes [elections are triggered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286135/467090) by the [departure of moderators](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7945/5029).